# Timestamp in JPQL query parameter not converted to UTC

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I know there are tons of timezone related questions on stackoverflow already, but sadly I didn't find one describing my problem.

The entity in question is an event and has a start and end as `java.util.Date`. On the database these are saved as timestamps in UTC.

I currently try to develop a method that gets all events overlapping a certain period. The query itself works, but the parameters are sent to the DB in my local timezone instead of UTC.

```
public List<EventEntity> getEventsInPeriod(Date start, Date end) {
    return em.createQuery("Select e from EventEntity e where e.startTime < :periodEnd and e.endTime > :periodStart", EventEntity.class)
        .setParameter("periodStart", start)
        .setParameter("periodEnd", end)
        .getResultList();
```

If a call `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` before executing the query, the correct result is returned.

I thought `Date` was like a timestamp (relative to unix start) and thus not timezone sensitive. When I look at the query in the logs, I can see that the date is passed as string in the current timezone. For example: `2020-08-01 15:30:00.0`

Comment: I don't understand the issue. How are you creating the start/end Date objects. If you create using "2020-08-01 15:30:00.0", this string is formatted in the local timezone and not going to be the same as "2020-08-01 15:30:00.0 UTC". It may also have to do with the database, the type used for the column and it's default timezone handling.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found is to add the current timezone offset to the dates before passing them to the query.

```
Date startInUtc = new Date(start.getTime() + offset);
...
query.setParameter("periodStart", startInUtc)
```

This is not very nice, because for persisting dates they are converted automatically and for querying I have to do this manually. So I'm still open for better solutions.